# Google timeline custom tooltip (bug shift)

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

Я кастомизировал тултип.
Но при изменении диапазона фильтрации, тултип рассинхронизируется с блоком.
[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/gsv48wqg/)

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
            packages: ['controls']
        });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawVisualization() {
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
                document.getElementById('dashboard'));

            var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'control',
                'options': {
                    // Filter by the date axis.
                    'filterColumnIndex': 2,
                    'ui': {
                        'chartType': 'LineChart',
                        'chartOptions': {
                            'width': 985,
                            'height': 70,
                            'chartArea': {
                                width: '80%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
                                height: '80%'
                            },
                            'hAxis': {
                                'baselineColor': 'none'
                            }
                        },
                        // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the stock.
                        // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
                        'chartView': {
                            'columns': [2, 3]
                        }
                    }
                },
                // Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
                //'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(1380740460000), 'end': new Date(1380740480000)}}
            });

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn({
                type: 'string',
                id: 'TestAction'
            });
            data.addColumn({
                type: 'string',
                id: 'dummy bar label'
            });
            data.addColumn({
                type: 'date',
                id: 'Start'
            });
            data.addColumn({
                type: 'date',
                id: 'End'
            });
            data.addColumn({
                type: 'number',
                id: 'id'
            });
            data.addColumn({
                type: 'string',
                role: 'tooltip',
                p: {
                    html: true
                }
            });
            data.addRows([
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 0, 25, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 0, 0),   1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 40, 0),  1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 2, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 2, 40, 0),  1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 3, 15, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 0, 0),   1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 40, 0),  1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 5, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 6, 40, 0),  1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 7, 10, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 7, 40, 0),  1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 8, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 9, 40, 0),  1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 21, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 22, 40, 0), 1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 23, 15, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 0, 0),  1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 40, 0), 1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 25, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 26, 40, 0), 1, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 27, 10, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 27, 40, 0), 2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 28, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 29, 40, 0), 2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 30, 15, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 31, 0, 0),  2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 32, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 33, 40, 0), 2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 34, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 36, 0, 0),  2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 37, 10, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 38, 40, 0), 2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 39, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 40, 40, 0), 2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 21, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 22, 40, 0), 2, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 23, 15, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 0, 0),  1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 40, 0), 1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 25, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 26, 40, 0), 1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 27, 10, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 27, 40, 0), 1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 28, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 29, 40, 0), 1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 42, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 42, 40, 0), 1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 43, 15, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 44, 0, 0),  1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 44, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 44, 40, 0), 1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 45, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 46, 40, 0), 1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 47, 10, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 47, 40, 0), 2, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 48, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 49, 40, 0), 2, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 50, 15, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 51, 0, 0),  2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 52, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 53, 40, 0), 2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 54, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 56, 0, 0),  2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 57, 10, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 58, 40, 0), 2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['MO Call', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 59, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 59, 50, 0), 2, '<p>MO Call</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 1, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 1, 40, 0),  2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 3, 15, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 4, 0, 0),   2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 4, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 4, 40, 0),  2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 5, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 6, 40, 0),  2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 7, 10, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 7, 40, 0),  2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 8, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 13, 9, 40, 0),  2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 10, 15, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 11, 0, 0),  2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 12, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 13, 40, 0), 2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 14, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 16, 0, 0),  2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 17, 10, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 18, 40, 0), 2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 19, 20, 0), new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 20, 40, 0), 2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 0, 10, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 0, 30, 0),  2, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 0, 45, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 0, 0),   1, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 2, 10, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 2, 25, 0),  1, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 3, 15, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 0, 0),   1, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 5, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 6, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 7, 10, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 7, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Browser', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 8, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 9, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Browser</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 2, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 2, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 3, 15, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 0, 0),   1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 4, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 5, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 6, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 7, 10, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 7, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['Youtube', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 8, 20, 0),  new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 9, 40, 0),  1, '<p>Youtube</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 0, 10, 0),     new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 0, 30, 0),  1, '<p>WIFI</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 0, 45, 0),     new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 0, 0),   1, '<p>WIFI</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 20, 0),     new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 1, 40, 0),  1, '<p>WIFI</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 21, 20, 0),    new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 22, 40, 0), 1, '<p>WIFI</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 23, 15, 0),    new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 0, 0),  1, '<p>WIFI</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 20, 0),    new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 24, 40, 0), 1, '<p>WIFI</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 25, 20, 0),    new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 26, 40, 0), 1, '<p>WIFI</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 27, 10, 0),    new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 27, 40, 0), 1, '<p>WIFI</p>'],
                ['WIFI', '', new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 28, 20, 0),    new Date(2013, 10, 2, 12, 29, 40, 0), 1, '<p>WIFI</p>']
            ]);

            var colors = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++)
                colors.push(data.getValue(i, 4) == 2 ? '#f00' : '#00f');

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'Timeline',
                'containerId': 'chart',
                'options': {
                    'width': 900,
                    'height': 600,
                    'chartArea': {
                        width: '80%',
                        height: '80%'
                    },
                    'colors': colors
                },
                'view': {
                    'columns': [0, 1, 2, 3]
                }

            });

            function hoverHandler(e) {
                if (e.row != null)
                    $(".google-visualization-tooltip").html(data.getValue(e.row, 5)).css({
                        width: "auto",
                        height: "auto"
                    });
            }

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
                var charts = chart.getChart();
                google.visualization.events.addListener(charts, 'onmouseover', hoverHandler);
            });

            dashboard.bind(control, chart);
            dashboard.draw(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Кто ни будь видит причину этой ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что вы меняете стиль тултипа: `.css(...`

Уберите вызов этого метода, а чтобы выравнивать элемент по содержанию в стиле пропишите:

```
div.google-visualization-tooltip { height: auto !important; width: auto !important}
```

**UPD:**
Дело в том, что `e.row` это айди «видимого» элемента ячейки.

Чтобы получить *глобальный* айди надо использовать метод `getTableRowIndex`

Я поправил ваш фиддл, должно работать:
https://jsfiddle.net/1ho48oq2/

Comment: Вероятно вы не поняли проблему.
После того как левый скрол сдвинут содержимое тултипа перестаёт совпадать с заголовком строки.

P.S. я знаю что data.getValue(e.row, 5) возвращает номер блока отличного от того на который реально произошло наведение курсора, но пока проблему не решил.